# Create a Decision Tree With Condition in String Format

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, decision-tree

I have a condition like below which is saved in database. Each condition has an outcome. I display the available outcomes in a combobox. When the user selects an outcome, I have to display the decision tree for this outcome.

Example:

```
COND1 AND (COND2 OR COND3 AND COND4 OR (COND5 AND COND6))
```

A condition shall be like AGE > 10, DOB IS NOT NULL, X IN TABLE(Y) etc. I need to first extract all the conditions separately and then using the AND, OR & Braces, I have to display them like a decision tree in C#. I have planned to use Accord.Net. Is there a simpler one available, becoz Accord.Net has more features which I don't need.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a tool that will generate a Decision Tree from a list of conditions that have already been determined from your database, and that there is an assumption that all cases have been considered and lead to an outcome in the system.

There are a couple of challenges that I see in the creation of these rules.

First, it appears that you are trying to optimise your set of condition rules with a format that is supported by traditional decision trees.  Decision Trees usually learn from a given training set, rather than take a series of conditions and look to optimise the rule splits from there.  Given that you already know the conditions of your system, perhaps you could build a Knowledge-Based System that uses the known conditions and build sensible splits manually.

Secondly, Decision Trees are traditionally AND-only, whereas the conditions in your list contain OR conditions.  While it is theoretically possible to convert such rules into a table ([see here](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/251987165_Fast_convert_OR-decision_table_to_decision_tree)), I would suspect that there would be no common tool available that does what you need to do easily.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

this might be not what you need exactly

What I would do here is use an embedded scripting language and read the pieces of script from the database and get the scripting engine to execute them and return the outcome

javascript has several embedded engines - I use jint https://jint.codeplex.com/

Or python.net or lua